# Dataset connection in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have published a dataset in Azure Data Factory but there is no way I can access the dataset in the databricks.

The dataset was published from a service that is connected to AWS S3.
[Here's the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq7VE.png)

I have tried reading the documentation on Azure but most of them leads to suggesting dropping this data into Azure Data Lake Storage. Is that the only way to access the data in the databricks?

Please provide any good documentation links.

Comment: Just publishing the dataset on ADF does not mean there is actually any data in the S3 bucket. We are assuming that you have executed your pipeline successfully to copy the data from source to target(S3). If you have already done this, check the S3 bucket if the data is actually there. If yes, then you should be able to able to access from databricks. Probably best to update the question to show the execution of the pipeline, the data present in S3, the databricks code which you are executing to read the data and the error you are receiving.

Comment: Yes, the data is there in the S3. (Different team workspace) I can see the preview of it in ADF. (Another workspace owned by other team in the enterprise) And my databricks is running in a 3rd workspace. How do I access the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Azure Databricks to access data directly from AWS S3 by setting up the necessary credentials and configurations.

- In AWS, you need to create an IAM role that allows Azure Databricks to access data in your S3 bucket. The IAM role should have permissions to access the necessary S3 buckets and objects.

Know more about external locations and storage credentials and [Create an IAM role](https://docs.databricks.com/en/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-external-locations-and-credentials.html#step-1-create-an-iam-role)

[Access S3 buckets with Unity Catalog volumes or external locations](https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/amazon-s3.html#access-s3-buckets-with-unity-catalog-volumes-or-external-locations)

The below is the code will help you Read & Write S3 bucket:

**Reading the file from S3:**

```
dbutils.fs.ls("s3://my-bucket/external-location/path/to/data")
spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3://my-bucket/external-location/path/to/data")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3://my-bucket/external-location/path/to/data`")
```

**Writing the file:**

```
dbutils.fs.mv("s3://my-bucket/external-location/path/to/data", "s3://my-bucket/external-location/path/to/new-location")
df.write.format("parquet").save("s3://my-bucket/external-location/path/to/new-location")
```